# Java and Scala not working together

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have 2 projects, one maven java and another maven Scala.

The scala one is a library, that I want to use in my java application.

I have the following dependencies in both :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0-1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and as found on googling, this maven-scala-plugin in both apps

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The source & target specified in maven for both are java 1.6 and I'm using Netbeans (tried even from command-line but no use)

I build the scala project and then mark a system dependency to it in the maven java project.

Infact, I'm using the goose parser (scala project - https://github.com/jiminoc/goose)

But whenever I run the java project/file, I get `ClassNotFoundException` for the parser classes.

Tried everything out there for hours now but no success.

Please help.

Also, to mention I've tried building with scala version `2.10.4` but it also has the same issue.

Comment: For others landing here, I ended up using `Eclipse Juno 4.2` with `m2e`, `scala-ide` and `maven support for scala` plugins installed. I still followed the same rule, built the `scala` and used it as a dependency in my maven java project. I believe the issue was something related to versioning or missing jars.

Answer (score 0):

> I build the scala project and then mark a system dependency to it in the maven java project.

[System dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies):

> > Dependencies with the scope system are always available *and are not looked up in repository*. They are usually used to tell Maven about dependencies which are provided by the JDK or the VM.

Since your Scala project isn't provided by the JDK or the VM, it isn't a system dependency. You would run into exactly the same problem if you had two Java projects. Just remove `<scope>system</scope>`.

Comment: I have specified the jar to use and hence, `system` scope. I don't think removing `system` scope, will let me specify the jar to use.